# How can I create a aggregate plot in Python across a column?

Tags: python, plot

I want to make a graph with this Dataframe in Python:

[the DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cwJ6.png)

The `Age` column represent the age of people and the `Travel Insurance` column shows 1 for customer and 0 for non-customer.

Does anyone know how to make a graph to show the percentage of customers in each age category?

Thank you so much!

The expected outcome is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just find percentage based on age for varying ages, you can find the distribution of ages using Counter. Since you have not provided your DataFrame, I have assumed its column as a list on my own and carried out the procedure for you.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import seaborn as sns
ages = [28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,31,31
       ,31,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['age'] = ages
distribution = dict(Counter(df['age']))
x_ax = distribution.keys()
y_ax = list(distribution.values())
total = sum(y_ax)
for i in range(len(y_ax)):
    y_ax[i] = y_ax[i] * 100 / total  
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.bar(x_ax, y_ax)
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
```

This returns a blue monochrome plot, however matching the rest of your specifications.

[image]

Comment: Forgot to add the plot here, but from here its pretty straightforward

Comment: Maybe u missunderstood my question. I give a picture of my expected outcome pls check it

Comment: I have added the plot for you as well, you can try other libraries for plotting such as Seaborn as well.